# Initilized string in c giving weird output

Tags: string, char, initialization, printf

Code shown below is intended to firstly manipulate the content of string p and then print its content. I have tested the code using two while loops and a printf statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char p[10] = "Hello";
    char *a = p;
    while(*a++)
        ;
    *a++ = '1';
    *a++ = '\0';
    a = p;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        putchar(a[i]);  
    putchar('\n');
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        putchar(p[i]);
    putchar('\n');
    printf("%s\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
xxx@ubuntu:~$ gcc -o test test.c
xxx@ubuntu:~$ ./test
Hello1
Hello1
Hello
```

Now, I have two question in my mind, first, Where is all the garbage values in first two lines to be shown after printing those 7 characters (including NULL). Secondly, Why the output of printf statement is 'Hello' while is should be 'Hello1'??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I. There's no garbage, for two reasons. One is that

```
char p[10] = "Hello";
```

is equivalent with

```
char p[10] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

i. e. it initializes the non-listed members to zero (more precisely, it initializes them as if they were `static`).

Second, even if they were truly uninitialized, you wouldn't have the right to expect garbage values. Reading an uninitialized variable is just undefined behavior, so there could be anything there.

II. Because you end up writing the `'1'` **past** the NUL terminator, since your approach of iterating through the string is wrong. So, the for loop with `putchar`, which iterates over each character will print all of them, including the past-the-NUL `'1'`, but `printf()` will terminate at the first NUL encountered. TL;DR: instead of

```
while *(a++);
```

you should have written

```
while (*a)
    a++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `;` after the while and do not increase the `a` twice...

Comment: no, that is **completely wrong.** You clearly didn't understand what the code should do. If you remove the semicolon after the `while`, it will fill up all of the string with `'1'`s. That's not what OP wants.

Comment: @user3477950 On what basis do you conclude **what kind of garbage** did the OP want?

Comment: This is not about the garbage. Your answer doesn't answer the first part, it answers the second part. (BTW, as to my conclusion: experience. I have seen a *lot* of people asking questions identical to this, and they always, unequivocally, without an exception, are looking for "garbage" because of lack of initialization, which is a myth.)

Comment: @user3477950 If you remove the semicolon after the `while`, it won't fill up the string with `1`s. It will put `1` at odd places only. This can be considered as intentional garbage - especially given the indentation of the line after the `while`.